# Connection refused Cordova Android (localhost)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, localhost, connection-refused

When running my App on Android, I get following Error message when trying to authenticate with the Spotify API (after redirecting back):

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED (http://localhost/index.html#access_token=...)
```

Logging in works, but redirecting back to my index.html form Cordova won't.

However, in the config.xml, I've set `<content src="http://localhost/index.html" />`, so exactly the same URL, just without the other params, and the index.html loads as expected. Even if I copy the URL I'm redirected to (where the error comes from) and paste it as the content src, there is still no error, so it's just the redirection I guess?

I also tried to set `localhost` to `10.0.0.2`, but then I wasn't able to view the `index.html`

Comment: So, for now I've found a pretty bad but working work-around. I open the auth-page with cordova-inappbrowser and add a event listener for errors upon loading a page. When an error appears, the app should just get the loaded url, close inappbrowser and load the url in the webview, which works, since redirecting somehow won't work in webview